# Please help, I am stuck on gnu grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grub-efi

A while back I decided to install Ubuntu on dual boot on my windows 10 computer. Things worked fine, until I encountered some bugs on Ubuntu. I thought I did something incorrect during the installation, so I decided to reinstall Ubuntu. I picked to erase the previous version of Ubuntu installed(Ubuntu 20.10) and replace it with 20.04.

The installation seemed to be working fine, until I encountered a strange error saying something like grub-install /dev/sda failed, this is a fatal error. I restarted the computer and bumped into the gnu grub. I can no longer even access windows 10. I googled a bunch of tutorials but alas, none of them worked.

Please help!

Comment: In fact, I would also be fine if anybody can give me a solution that will switch back to the standard windows bootloader.

Comment: Did you install *over* Windows? Because you should be able to direct your BIOS to boot to your Windows installation.  (re)Installing/Removing Ubuntu does not affect your Windows installation unless you tell the installer to overwrite it.  You're better of to fully remove Ubuntu than to try to install an older version over a newer version - that's how you end up with a broken Ubuntu

Comment: I did install over windows, but my computer runs on UEFI settings, which are not the same as BIOS. I don't know how I'm going to fully remove the ubuntu without having access to windows. Before I tried reinstalling ubuntu, things were actually working pretty well. I could pick between booting ubuntu and windows and all. I just don't know how to remove the GNU grub and completely remove ubuntu and just get back to the normal windows bootloader.

Comment: If UEFI, you should always be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. Unless totally broken and then you need the Windows repair disk that you of course made when you first got system. Grub only boots working Windows. And Windows updates turn fast start up back on, so grub will not boot it. Directly boot Windows and turn fast start up off or make other repairs. Then grub should boot it again.

Comment: If you've overwritten Windows you will need to reinstall it. One good thing about your Ubuntu installation media is that it's a very good recovery tool. You can boot from installation media and "Try Ubuntu" which gives you a fully functioning Ubuntu without having to install anything.  The "Disks" application will allow you to format (erase) your hard drives so you can start with a clean slate to reinstall Windows and/or a dual boot config if you still want to do that

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may have tried to install grub on /dev/sda which is incorrect for UEFI systems. You should have installed it on /dev/sda1 which is most likely your EFI partition.

You still should be able to recover from this without re-installing. Check out the following link to get some idea on how to do this.

https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/

Without knowing the exact details of your installation it is not possible to provide you the detailed guidelines.

If you cannot find the linux boot images using the instructions of the above link you can use the Windows10 installation disk to restore the boot loader. If you do not have a Windows installation disk, go to Microsoft website, download the Win10 installation image, burn a DVD. Boot the DVD and select repair option.